# How to handle recursion with monix's observable?

Tags: scala, recursion, monix

Using [monix](https://monix.io/) I'm trying to traverse a graph by building an Observable[Node] and using a breadth first algorithm. 
However there I have a bit of a recursion problem. Here is a snippet illustrating my problem:

```
package gp

import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import monix.reactive._


object HelloObservable {

  type Node = Int

  //real case fetch next node across the network so the signature 
  //has to be Node -> List[Task[Node]]
  def nexts(i : Node) : List[Task[Node]] =
    List(Task(i), Task(i+1))

  def go(i :Node) : Task[Iterator[List[Node]]] =
    Task.sequence(nexts(i).sliding(100,100).map(Task.gatherUnordered))

  def explore(r: Node): Observable[Node] = {
    val firsts = for {
      ilr <- Observable.fromTask(go(r))
      lr <- Observable.fromIterator(ilr)
      r <- Observable.fromIterable(lr)
    } yield r

    firsts ++ firsts.flatMap(explore)
  }


  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val obs = explore(0)

    val cancelable = obs
      .dump("O")
      .subscribe()

    scala.io.StdIn.readLine()

  }

}
```

The observable stop after the first iteration. Can anyone hint me why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is not related to recursion. I think it comes from the fact that you use `sliding` which returns an `Iterator`. The major difference between `Iterator` and `Iterable` is that you can consume `Iterator` only once and after that all you are left with is an empty `Iterator`. It means when you do `firsts.flatMap` there is nothing left in the `Observable.fromIterator(ilr)` and so nothing is produced.

Fundamentally I don't think you can do a breadth-first search if you can't hold (most part of) the prefix in the memory. But since your `nexts` already returns `List`, I assume that you can afford having two copies of that list in the memory. And the second copy is a materialized result of the `sliding`. So your fixed code would be something like this:

```
object HelloObservable {

    import monix.eval.Task
    import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
    import monix.reactive._

    type Node = Int

    //real case fetch next node across the network so the signature
    //has to be Node -> List[Task[Node]]
    def nexts(i: Node): List[Task[Node]] = List(Task(i), Task(i + 1))

    def go(i: Node): Task[List[List[Node]]] =
      Task.sequence(nexts(i).sliding(100, 100).toList.map(Task.gatherUnordered))


    def explore(r: Node): Observable[Node] = {
      val firsts = for {
        ilr <- Observable.fromTask(go(r))
        lr <- Observable.fromIterable(ilr)
        r <- Observable.fromIterable(lr)
      } yield r
      firsts ++ firsts.flatMap(explore)
    }


    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

      val obs = explore(0)

      val cancelable = obs
        .dump("O")
        .subscribe()

      scala.io.StdIn.readLine()

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I feel a bit stupid XD
But since my problem was not really related to the question I asked, what is the proper StackOverflow etiquette ? should I delete my question ?

Comment: @lorilan, I don't know whether such thing as an official SO etiquette exists at all :-) Probably the closest one on this topic is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). As deleting this question will probably result in loss of reputation for me, I have a selfish motive to suggest against it. Still, I don't think that deleting this question is good idea. IMHO you should delete only irrecoverably bad questions with no good answers (i.e. pure information noise). However, if you can think of a way to improve future discoverability - you are welcome to edit your post.